# How to translate this Python for loop into Tensorflow (if possible)

Tags: python, for-loop, tensorflow, zip

I would like to convert this very simple Python for loop into Tensorflow without breaking the TF computational graph. Is there any way I can do it? (if any)

This is the for loop where A, B and C are tensors.

```py
  for a, b in zip(A, B):
    if 0 <= a:
      C[a] += b
```

I am very new to Tensorflow and I am aware that this may be an unreasonable question to ask (as per how TF works) and I would appreciate any comments about that if I am too far from reality too. Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use loops in tensorflow. [`tf.scatter_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd) is an appropriate function for your question. An example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

A = [-1,2,3,1]
B = [-2,4,6,2]
C = [-1,2,3,1,7,6]

for a, b in zip(A, B):
    if 0 <= a:
        C[a] += b
print('your result:\n',C)

A = tf.constant([-1,2,3,1])
B = tf.constant([-2,4,6,2])
C = tf.constant([-1,2,3,1,7,6])

mask_B = tf.boolean_mask(B,tf.greater_equal(A,0))
mask_A = tf.boolean_mask(A,tf.greater_equal(A,0))
C = tf.scatter_nd(tf.expand_dims(mask_A,axis=-1), mask_B, tf.shape(C))+C
# if C type is tf.Variable, you can use tf.scatter_nd_add
# C = tf.scatter_nd_add(C, tf.expand_dims(mask_A,axis=-1), mask_B)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print('tensorflow version:\n',sess.run(C))

your result:
 [-1, 4, 7, 7, 7, 6]
tensorflow version:
 [-1  4  7  7  7  6]
```